# bookdown::publish_book - error when publishing Rmarkdown in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

When I try to publish a book to bookdown by running the command:

```
bookdown::publish_book(render = "none", account="my_account", server="bookdown.org")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in rsconnect::deploySite(siteDir = getwd(), siteName = name, account = account, : 
index file with site entry not found in C:\Users\...\...
```

I have managed to connect to bookdown with the command `rsconnect::connectUser(server = 'bookdown.org')`.

and when I run `rsconnect::accounts` I get a positive response:

```
    name       server
1 my_user bookdown.org
```

**What could be causing this error?** Thanks

Comment: What is a bookdown index file?

Answer (score 1):

in the end, I just used `rsconnect` instead:

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(rsconnect)

connectUser(account = "my_user", server = "bookdown.org", quiet = TRUE)

# reder app
render("script.Rmd")
deployApp(appFiles = "script.html")
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. But what is script.Rmd and script.html?